# how to pull a column named "NUMBER" from Oracle through Ms Query in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, excel-2010

I know, I know...The column shouldn't be named "NUMBER", but it was here before I was, and I can't change it for now. At the moment, I only have read access to this database, and I was told it would be changed...soonish...

I've tried referencing it as `Table."NUMBER"` and that works when querying directly from Oracle, but for some reason, I still get the infamous `ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or columns specification` error when I reference it that way in MS Query.  I also tried `Table.""NUMBER""`, `"Table."NUMBER""`, `Table.'"NUMBER"'`, and `'Table."NUMBER"'`, but each of these gave me an error from MS Query saying it wasn't expecting the punctuation in the select column list.

Does this have something to do with the way MS Query handles double quotes? Is there any way to make sure that the double quotes around NUMBER make it to Oracle without MS Query throwing an error?

My query is really simple...except for this part.

```
Select Table."NUMBER"
From Table
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: @Mike, didn't OP mentioned he already tried the same

Comment: @Mike  I did try that. When I do that, MS Query gives me an error saying it didn't expect the double quotes in the select column list.

Comment: @Rahul indeed he did, I'll delete the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
SELECT table."NUMBER" AS a_number FROM table
```

or create a view referencing the table and rename the column as required

Aliases solve a lot of problems with names.  I suspect that the issue you were having is not with running the query in Oracle but the result that comes back from Oracle.  An alias allows the result set to be usable by Access.

Comment: Makes sense to me, and it's brilliant, yet simple. Thanks!

Comment: Just a note for anybody who sees this in the future. This only works after you've created the query in MS Query. Create the query without the questionable column. Then, once it's working, modify the SQL directly within the Query definition to add in the questionable column and alias.